# How to bypass /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm?

Tags: perl

I'm getting a cryptic error when I try to debug a Perl script:

```
% perl -d path/to/script.pl
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

Attempt to reload Carp/Heavy.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 33.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<1>
```

I've come across other mentions of similar errors online, and there seems to be a problem with in the version of `Carp.pm` installed with Centos 6.

At any rate, the version of `Carp` installed under `/usr/share/perl5` is 1.11, whereas the one that I have installed under `/my/local/lib/perl5` is 1.38.

I don't have `/usr/share/perl5` anywhere in my `PERL5LIB` environment variable, whereas I do have `/my/local/lib/perl5` in it.  Still, no matter what I do, the `Carp` that I get when I attempt `use Carp` is the one under `/usr/share/perl5`, not the one under `/my/local/lib/perl5`.

How can I have give `/my/local/lib/perl5` priority at the time of searching for `Carp.pm` and `Carp/Heavy.pm`?

---

**EDIT:** Per Borodin's comment

```
% which -a perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl

% perl -E 'say for @INC'
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
.
```

The output above contradicts what I wrote in my original post; this is because the script in question is a CGI script that uses `use lib` to specify `/my/local/lib/perl5`.  It does this before any other `use <PACKAGE>;` statements, but this does not seem to help.

In the process of collecting the info for this EDIT, I discovered that the error goes away if, in addition to the `use lib ...` statement within the code, I put `/my/local/lib/perl5` in `PERL5LIB` (I had originally stated).  This is not representative of what will happen when the script is run in production (as a CGI script), but at least it will allow me to debug it now.

Comment: What is the output of `which -a perl` and `perl -E'say for @INC`? Please edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: @Borodin: thank you; in the process of answering your comment, I discovered a workaround; the question is now a mess; sorry about that; please feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Your question is fine, but "work-arounds" are less than ideal. Remember that every page of *Stack Overflow* is most useful because it will help countless people beyond the OP. Please write an answer to your own question that describes your journey to success. You may accept your own answer after a delay of a few days.

Comment: Perl will go through `@INC` and use the first module found.